# How to change locale directory?

Tags: unix, makefile, autotools

Is there a way to change to default locale directory to another one? Normally when you type

```
 ./configure
 make
 make install
```

the default directory is $(datadir)/locale, which is expanded to /usr/[local/]share/locale. I'm using autotools, so I can't manually modify po/Makefile because is overwritten :(

I'm trying to change it to my package install dir:

$(prefix)/share/@PACKAGE@/locale

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

One of the available flags to `./configure` is usually `--localedir` which, presumably, changes what you want. Though I'm not sure why you want to change that as such.

Comment: So I can have all the files in the same folder